# Xcode 8.3.1 says to replace size with coder what does this mean?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Incorrect argument label in call have "size" expected "coder "
Any help ?
  lass GameViewController: UIViewController {

```
var scene: GameScene!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Configure the view
    let skView = view as! SKView
    skView.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false

    // Create and configure the scene
    scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)
    scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

    // Present the scene
    skView.presentScene(scene)
}
```

Comment: please input some code to understand your problem

Comment: Where you see
""scene = GameScene(size: skView.bounds.size)""
xcode says to replace size with coder

Answer (score 0):

- If you override all of the superclass designated initializers, you'll
  inherit the superclass convenience initializers. (See Swift docs,
  "Initialization" -> "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" -> "Rule 2".)
  I think in this case that means you can define an init(property1:)
  that just calls through to super and you should able to use
  init(value1:value2) for subclass initialization.

---

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/30537